# Extracting a name from a NETCDF file with Python using netCDF4

Tags: python, python-3.x, netcdf, netcdf4

I have been fiddling with the netCDF4 package for a while, and no matter what I try, I am unable to load the variable names. I will show you what I mean by it. The simple code I have written is as follows:

```
import netCDF4 as netcdf
import numpy as np

f = netcdf.Dataset("pressureOutput/QOUT_500.Netcdf","r")
   
variablesList = f.variables

print(variablesList)
```

The output on the console is:

```
{'variables0': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 variables0(dim0)
    name: u
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (163840,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'variables1': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 variables1(dim0)
    name: v
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (163840,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'variables2': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 variables2(dim0)
    name: rho
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (163840,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'variables3': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 variables3(dim0)
    name: p
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (163840,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'variables4': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 variables4(dim0)
    name: YH2
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (163840,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'variables5': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
( MORE OUTPUT)
(...)
(...)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'variables24': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 variables24(dim0)
    name: heatRelease
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (163840,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used}
```

As one can see, the variable 'variables0' has a property named name, which should output u. I want to retrieve this information for every one of the variables (u, v, rho, p, etc.). However, if I try

```
f['variables0'].name
```

I get 'variables0' as an output. How can I retrieve this information from the file?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve this problem by converting it to a list:

```
list(variablesList)
```